# spring boot 2.2.1 web application deployment isssue on Tomcat version 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment

I am unable to deploy spring boot(v2.2.1) web application in Tomcat 7.0 web server due to error on start the application.

The following error is displayed.

```
FAIL - Application at context path /<project-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/<project-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]].
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace if any.

Comment: remove your unwanted dependecies from pom.xml and make sure you have configured correct configs in application.properties. Else the dependency will expect the configuration on start up. Example if you have added security related dependency in pom.xml and no configuration made in application.properties then deployment will not be done.